# draw a qlabel after text in qtextedit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextedit, qlabel

I have a QTextEdit in which I want to write some text, and then a QLabel afterwards, like this

```
"Blah blah" [Label text]
```

My thought was to first write the text, use the moveCursor function to move the cursor to the end of the document, then draw the label in the current cursor position, as in

```
append("Blah blah");
moveCursor(QTextCursor::End);
label->move(cursor().pos());
```

However the results in the label being shown in the upper left corner of the editor. How can I get the label to be drawn after the text as above?

To be a bit more clear, consider

```
class myTextEdit::QTextEdit{
    explicit myTextEdit(QWidget* parent=0):
    QTextEdit(parent){
        append("blah blah ");
        update();
        auto l=new QLabel(this);
        l->setText(QString("label text"));
        l->setVisible(true);
        moveCursor(QTextCursor::End);
        l->move(cursor().pos());
        l->update();
}
```

I want the output to be "blah blah",immediately followed by a label that says "label text", however the above code causes the label to be drawn in the extreme bottom right corner of the screen .

Comment: you could provide a [mcve] to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: what do you mean exactly? i want to help you

Comment: I think the OP wants to put a `QLabel` widget on top of the `QTextEdit` at the cursor position.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes that is right, sorry if the wording was unclear

Comment: It could be the coordinate systems are different. It could be caused by making the label a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I started with google and found [Put QWidget in a QTextEdit](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/23994-Put-QWidget-in-a-QTextEdit) in the Qt Forum.

Thinking twice, I came to the conclusion that the solution of OP should work as well (though, may be, with some limitations which might or might not be acceptable).

Then I realized that the OP did a serious mistake:

```
l->move(cursor().pos());
```

does not what OP intends to do.

`cursor()` is inherited and is actually [`QWidget::cursor()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#cursor-prop) returning the mouse cursor for this widget.

For what the OP intends to do it had to be [`QTextEdit::textCursor()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textCursor) instead. Though, I couldn't find anything in [`QTextCursor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html) returning the required view coordinates.

Instead, I found (two variations of) [`QTextEdit::cursorRect()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#cursorRect-1) which I considered as most promising candidates.

Fiddling with the code of OP, I realized another issue:

The call of `update()` in `TextEdit::TextEdit()` seemed to be used with the intention to get proper view coordinates for text cursor. [`QWidget::update()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) doesn't anything else than requesting a (re-)paint. (Debugging my sample code approved it once more: I got always `0, 0` as position.)

I'm still struggling with what detail of layout is available when. Certain things are done in events. So, it is impossible to request proper values before the event loop is even started (in `QApplication::exec()`). However, in certain situations a simple `show()` is enough to ensure proper values – especially regarding layout.

However, after having been reminded to this, I re-arranged the code a bit and finally got what I believe the OP intended to do.

`testQTextEditWithQLabel.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QTextEdit qTextEdit;
  qTextEdit.append("OP said: blah blah ");
  qTextEdit.show();
  QLabel qLbl(QString("label text"), &qTextEdit);
  qTextEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor::End);
  const QRect qRect = qTextEdit.cursorRect();
  qDebug() << "Rect:" << qRect;
  qLbl.show();
  qLbl.move(qRect.left(), qRect.top());
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQTextEditWithQLabel.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQTextEditWithQLabel.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiling and testing in [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org) (64 bit) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 

$ make
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQTextEditWithQLabel.o testQTextEditWithQLabel.cc
g++  -o testQTextEditWithQLabel.exe testQTextEditWithQLabel.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 

$ ./testQTextEditWithQLabel
Rect: QRect(116,4 1x14)
```

with the following window:

[image: snapshot of testQTextEditWithQLabel]

I'm not quite sure how well this will work together when scrolling comes into play but this might or might not be an issue of OP.

Comment: Thank you. I was indeed under the mistaken impression that moveCursor would (as its name suggests) move the object referred to by cursor(), when in fact it moves the object referred to by textCursor(). The docs seem very unclear on this point; the description of this function starts off as "Moves the cursor...".

Comment: @MikeHawk I needed a little but to understand your comment but finally I got it. Yepp, the text might be mis-leading but have a look at the function signatures. Then it becomes rather obvious what cursor they mean. (The distinction of mouse cursor and text cursor is IMHO an old topic. In ancient times, concerning OSF/Motif, I once read "cursor" and "caret". Cursor was mouse cursor, caret the text cursor. Coming from DOS or console programming, this was really confusing for me...)

Comment: @MikeHawk I shouldn't repeat the "In the past, everything was better..." habit but before Qt, we did gtkmm on Windows (until the Windows support became that bad that we moved to Qt). IMHO, GTK+/gtkmm has a very precise naming scheme in its API which I always liked very much. After moving to Qt, I missed it a bit. (On the other hand, now we've rather stable but still portable GUI for our S/W and that was worth the move.)

Comment: I see what you mean about the signatures, although I can't help but wish the docs themselves were a bit more fastidious about this distinction. Anyway your comment seems to resolve the issue I was having. Cheers!